# SSL Mismatched Address Certificate Error on IIS 7

Tags: ssl, iis

We have a local application server (trisha0002), and on this server we have an application (FlexibleBenefits). When we install SSL for this application, it gives Mismatched Address. What can be the reason of this ?

[image]

Comment: This belongs to serverfault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Issued To field is invalid. The field should be the domain name, not the path. So the value would be `trisha0002`, and not `http://trisha0002/FlexibleBenefits/`.

As a result, IE is validating the domain against the certificate and the certificate Issued To doesn't match the domain, so it fails.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate common name is incorrect. It shouldn't be an URL (`https://trisha0002/FlixibleBenefits`) but just a host name (in your case trish0002).

Also, you should use a fully qualified host name, not just the server name. Otherwiese, the same certificate could be used to identify different hosts belonging to different networks.

In other words, you apparently have important issues with your certificate authority: it does not do its job properly.